# lateral function for Variant columns creating cross join in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 3 columns, (Datatype is Variant).
Values are
Column1
[5,55]

Column2
[3,52,66]

Column3
[4,53]

Iam using the below logic to get the values..

```
`select 
pc.value::string as column1,
pc1.value::string as column2,
pc2.value::string as column3
from table as RCV 
lateral flaten(input=>RCV.column1) PC
lateral flaten(input=>RCV.column2) PC1
lateral flaten(input=>RCV.column3) PC2`
```

I got 12 rows for the above SQL, its doing a CROSS JOIN. Need 3 rows, Please help, Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: There are a number of different ways to get three rows from the input, so it will help to provide the intended output.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, can you please give some sample ways

Comment: You need to provide the result you are trying to achieve, based on your sample data, before anyone can help you